# Can an offline user carry out database transactions specific to their uid in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, offline-caching

*The situation:*

User starts the app with no internet connection. I attempt to authenticate them anonymously in my launch activity and perform a database write to the reference ***'/users/$uid'***, in a database with this rule structure:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, if this situation occurs and the user then comes online will the queued database transaction actually be executed - or do I need to manually re-authenticate and retry the database transaction?

I'm not sure if the ***uid*** for anonymous authentication will be generated if the user is offline, so I don't think the database reference can be resolved.

> Reference links:
>
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

Comment: Would it be worthwhile finding a different _local_ storage solution, rather that using realtime database, seeing as the risk of an unauthenticated user attempting a database write to a DB of this structure and losing the transaction (for example across app restarts) would be high?

Comment: did you tried just disabling your 4g mobile data and just unplug your modem just before login in into your app and then re-plug it to see if the data is sent ?

Comment: If I disable the device's internet connection, do an action that would normally require auth/trigger a database transaction, then the DB is unaffected.
**_EDIT:_** This happens both when simply reactivating internet connectivity and when restarting the app, then reactivating internet connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after testing this, I've found that:

- The uid cannot be relied upon between restarts if the user never had connectivity in the first place
- Database transactions which are performed locally - because you have setPersistence(true) - will be queued and synced with remote, regardless of whether the user has connectivity or not, but not if the DatabaseReference used contains a reference to the current user's uid, because this cannot be relied upon between restarts (such as in the scenario described in the question).

To get around this, I'm using local storage by means of SharedPreferences for the most basic data and waiting for connection before instantiating a DatabaseReference which references the user's uid.

Answer (score 1):

I would save the data in sharedpreferences or local DB (depends on the type of data you want to save).

After that either start background service and try to connect to your realtime database every 10mins or you want for the user next time they open the app and check if theres any authentication need to be checked.

For the background service i would recommend AlarmManger.

Comment: The object I wish to save is a POJO, not just a simple primitive type like _int_ or _String_ etc so I would require an entire other DB solution to use alongside Firebase - which is precisely what i'm trying to avoid. Thanks for trying to answer though.

Comment: Also, unfortunately _AlarmManager_ wouldn't preserve the intended work between app/device restarts. I looked into this - above API 21 it is generally recommended to use the _WorkManager_ Android architecture component. However, there are other options such as Evernote's _android-job_ library.